# How to deallocate array of class instances in C++?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I am making a little game, I store the map in an array, for a reason I think is needless to inform you about my map is not just a `char` array, I have made a class:

```cpp
enum Marks { N, Ex3, Ex2, Ex1, Pl, En, Pb, Eb};

class MC /*Map Component*/{
public:
    Marks Marked = Marks::N;
    char ch = '\0';
};
```

and my array is an array of instances of this class, but bcs, according to Visual Studio, my map is to big for the stack, I made heap allocation, `MC* map = new MC[1050]; // 15 * 70`

Everything works fine, until the player dies, the game ends and the time has come for the map to be deleted, `delete[] map` throws `Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap([some hexadecimal number, an address probably], [some hexadecimal number, an address probably])`

I know I can use `vector`s, but I just dont want, I want to learn more about memory managment, get more familiar with pointers etc

---

Edit: `Visual Studio` also opens a file named `delete_scalar.cpp`.
Code of that file:

```
//
// delete_scalar.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete.
//
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>
#include <vcstartup_internal.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// delete() Fallback Ordering
//
// +-------------+
// |delete_scalar<----+-----------------------+
// +--^----------+    |                       |
//    |               |                       |
// +--+---------+  +--+---------------+  +----+----------------+
// |delete_array|  |delete_scalar_size|  |delete_scalar_nothrow|
// +--^----^----+  +------------------+  +---------------------+
//    |    |
//    |    +-------------------+
//    |                        |
// +--+--------------+  +------+-------------+
// |delete_array_size|  |delete_array_nothrow|
// +-----------------+  +--------------------+

_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

And after some tests I found out that the program crashes after `delete[]`, what I mean:

```
//
// code that runs the game
//
std::cout << endl << "Before delete";
_getch();
delete[] map;
std::cout << endl << "After delete";
_getch();
return; //function is void and is not main()
```

Output:

```
Before delete
//me pressing something
After delete
//me pressing something
//program crashes
```

Apology: bcs `Visual Studio` opened `delete_scalar.cpp` I assumed that `delete[]` was causing the program to crash, now I just dont know, I am confused.

Comment: You have not provided a [mre].

Comment: Check if the value of map after call to new is the same as value of map before calling delete[]. Probably you have modified the pointer.

Comment: Your array doesn't seem too large for the stack (1MB by default), but this is not the question. I can think of two explanations for your problem: 1) you don't pass to delete the value returned by new; 2) you overwrite a descriptor of the allocated array by doing some out-of-range access.

Comment: you almost never want to manually deal with cleaning up stuff. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: if you want to learn more about memory mangagment you could write your own smart pointer / smart array. `new` and `delete` in the wild are dangerous

Comment: @AdamF I checked, I saw your comment and checked, `cout << map` just when I created it gives `007D5DB8` and so does just before I `delete` it

Comment: _Also, for some reason sizeof(MC); returns 8, can someone explain please?_ What's wrong with 8? Did you expect something different? `sizeof (Marks)` is probably 4. `sizeof (char)` is 1. The rest is alignment / padding. -> [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3266ae00a49723a6)

Comment: @Scheff I thought that it would be five, bcs if I remember correctly I had seen somewhere that a class just puts a bunch of bytes next to each other, based on each member's size, that didn't make sense to me, what you said now makes much more sense but bcs I had not seen anything anywhere else I stayed with that, thank you for confirming my assumptions

Comment: Yeah. For this, you have to remark it for explicit packing (but I don't know how exactly). `g++` tries to beat the most out of your CPU. For this, well-aligned data is better. Hence, the padding. ;-)

Comment: @Mansoor I wasn't before and I am not even now sure what causes the crash, I updated the question bcs I found out that `delete[]` might not be the problem

Comment: @platinoob_ I think you meant to Scheff, not me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am terribly sorry, bcs it turns out that I am a total idiot, my stupidness knows no bounds. The reason I am saying this: as the game runs certain type of objects get created, deleted and recreated all the time and bcs of that I was allocating them to the heap, but I forgot to make my program `delete` them in case they were "alive" at the moment the player dies, I cant believe how much of an idiot I am to spend 3 days on something like this.

Thank you to everyone trying to solve my problem even if they had not the needed information, I didn't knew exactly what information was needed so...yeah, I am sorry